# Clever Statement that can be backed up later

Tags: single-word-requests

There are people who are very clever in what they say, especially political and religious leaders. They choose words very carefully. They make statements in a way so that if people oppose the words they can get back to the original words spoken and back it up itself.

Example-

- Religious Leader: There is Almost NO evidence against Evolution.

  Critic: There is many evidence, how come there is none.

  Religious Leader: I said, "Almost No"

I remember a word like "come-back" statement but not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Four words worth considering together are **[spin](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spin)**, **[pivot](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pivot)**, **[talking point](http://something%20that%20lends%20support%20to%20an%20argument)**, and **[weasel word](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/weasel%20words)**. From M-W:

> **spin** (v): to present (information) with a particular spin, e.g., *spin* the statistics
>
> **spin** (n): a special point of view, emphasis, or interpretation presented for the purpose of influencing opinion, e.g., put the most favorable *spin* on the findings
>
> **pivot**:  to turn on or as if on a pivot
>
> **talking point**: something that lends support to an argument
>
> **weasel word**: a word used in order to evade or retreat from a direct or forthright statement or position

Politicians, religious leaders, ideologues, partisans, and others (not to imply that these categories are mutually exclusive or exhaustive) often present their arguments in terms of **talking points** incorporating a particular **spin** and replete with **weasel words**. When called or pressed on that **spin**, they **pivot** back to their **talking points**, making full use of the **weasel words**. What are we talking about mostly in the context of the OP's question? **Weasel words**.

Comment: thank you so much bro

Comment: @Tanvir my pleasure. Good question.

Answer (score 0):

Comeback statement is not English, try typing it into a corpus, such as Skell, you'll get zero hits. I'd go with something like flawless or foolproof statement.

Answer (score 0):

You might try describing statements as "irrefutable" or "incontrovertible", both of which mean "impossible to deny or refute". https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/irrefutable